# How to set the size of a d3 symbol?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, svg

I can't figure out how to set the size of my d3 symbols in this:

```
        legendRectE
            .append('path')
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type((d) => { return d[2] }))
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return d[1];
            })
            .attr('stroke', 'black');
```

I tried to use `.size()` like this, but it didn't work:

```
        legendRectE
            .append('path')
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type((d) => { return d[2] }))
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return d[1];
            })
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .size(20*20);
```

When I try using `.size()` like that, I get an error: `[ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

So how can I set the size of my symbols in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to define the `size` in the symbol generator (the `d3.svg.symbol` function):

```
d3.svg.symbol().size(size).type(foo);
//size here-----------^
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var sizes = ["10", "50", "100", "200", "500", "1000", "2000"];

sizes.forEach((d, i) => {
  svg.append('path')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (10 + (i+1) * (i+1) * 5) + ",100)")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().size(d).type("diamond"))
    .style("fill", "gold")
    .attr('stroke', 'black');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo! So, specific to my code example, I changed `.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type((d) => { return d[2] }))` to `.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type((d) => { return d[2] }).size(20*20))` to make it work.

Comment: What's the scale or unit of measure of symbol size? How can it be modified dynamically, for example in response to a mouse hover in a transition sequence? Thanks

Comment: @Dinesh the unit is pixels (actually, square pixels). Regarding your question about modifying it, please post it as a new question, because it's hard answering this in the comments section.